# Use value in select on other input fields

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to use the values of this select field for use in other input field.

```
          <select class="form-control" id="size" name="size" onchange="divide()">

          <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $i_magneet; $i++) { echo '

                <option value="'.$magneet[$i][1].'|'.$magneet[$i][2].'|'.$magneet[$i][3].'">'.$magneet[$i][0].' cm</option>';

            } ?>

          </select>
```

When I echo `'.$magneet[$i][1].'|'.$magneet[$i][2].'|'.$magneet[$i][3].'` I get `80|21,52|40,95|15`

I have this JS code to send to other input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function divide()
{
   var size = (selectVeld.options.value).split('|');
    // inkoop
    document.getElementsByName('inkoop').value = size[0];
    // verkoop
    document.getElementsByName('verkoop').value = size[1];
    // transport
    document.getElementsByName('transport').value = size[2];
}
function validate_add()
</script>
```

There are the input fields:

```
      <input type="text" id="inkoop" name="inkoop" value="">
      <input type="text" id="verkoop" name="verkoop" value="">
      <input type="text" id="transport" name="transport" value="">
```

There is no value send to any of them, any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `selectVeld` in the HTML or defined in the Javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('inkoop')` will return a NodeList ([...]). So this `document.getElementsByName('inkoop').value = size[0];` assignment will not work.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thats' what Madhavan said too.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It does return a `NodeList`. But why do you say it will throw an error, just curious.

Comment: @PraveenKumar absolutely I'm confused on his comment

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Umm, you are wrong... [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)...

Comment: @Muiter I answered the question first. Kinda not fair... But anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

Modified your code a little

```js
function divide() {
  var size = (document.getElementById("size").value).split('|');
  // inkoop
  document.getElementById('inkoop').value = size[0];
  // verkoop
  document.getElementById('verkoop').value = size[1];
  // transport
  document.getElementById('transport').value = size[2];
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="size" name="size" onchange="divide(this)">
<option></option>
 <option value="80|21,52|40,95|15">80|21,52|40,95|15</option>';
  </select>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="inkoop" name="inkoop" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="verkoop" name="verkoop" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="transport" name="transport" value="">
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Plus I already answered something similar. The `size` won't have the value here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why not?

Comment: `document.getElementById("size").value` is invalid. Check it out. Not sure... It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your JavaScript. Few corrections and you are good:

1. Add a `this` parameter to `divide()`.
2. Pass the `this` parameter to `divide()`.
3. Use that to ingest the value using `document.getElementById()`.

```js
function divide(elem) {
  var size = (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value).split('|');
  console.log(size);
  // inkoop
  document.getElementById('inkoop').value = size[0];
  // verkoop
  document.getElementById('verkoop').value = size[1];
  // transport
  document.getElementById('transport').value = size[2];
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="size" name="size" onchange="divide(this)">
  <option value="0|0|0"></option>
  <option value="80|21,52|40,95|15">15 cm</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inkoop" name="inkoop" value="" />
<input type="text" id="verkoop" name="verkoop" value="" />
<input type="text" id="transport" name="transport" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByName` and pass `this` into `function onchange select` and get value like `e.value`

```js
function divide(e) {

  var size = e.value.split('|');
  // console.log(size);
  // inkoop
  document.getElementById('inkoop').value = size[0];
  // verkoop
  document.getElementById('verkoop').value = size[1];
  // transport
  document.getElementById('transport').value = size[2];
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="size" name="size" onchange="divide(this)">
<option></option>
 <option value="80|21,52|40,95|15">80|21,52|40,95|15</option>';
  </select>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="inkoop" name="inkoop" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="verkoop" name="verkoop" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="transport" name="transport" value="">
```

Comment: hows you get option in select

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Everyone copying mine? LoL. For some crazy reason I added that parentheses.

Comment: no bro @PraveenKumar its coming from ` document.getElementById("size").value)` here i remove its code between `()` and add `value code` so not LoL

Comment: @Bhargav Em, I was kidding.